# Fabric does not show new crashes when there is missing dSYM files from previous versions

Tags: ios, crashlytics, google-fabric

I am developing an in-house app for testing purposes.

Fabric warned me about missing dSYM files, so when i investigated the problem I realised that my project settings prevented creating a dSYM file. (Please note that i am NOT creating archives, installing apps directly to devices by selecting as target from xcode) So there is no dSYM file anywhere (not in archive, not in iTunesConnect etc) for this old versions.

Now in newer versions of my app, i am creating dSYM files and simulating new crashes, however Fabric does not show them to me because it says there are missing dSYM files from old versions. My crashlytics dashboard show %100 crash-free users for new versions even tough i am creating crashes on purpose.

Is there any way to make Fabric just forget about this old crashes? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Mike from Fabric here. If we don't get the missing dSYM within 7 days, then the crashes will not be processed and removed. However, missing a dSYM will have no affect on new crashes where a dSYM is present. It's unclear how you're testing, but if you're testing on the Simulator or on a device connected to your machine, you need to disconnect Xcode's debugger. When using a device connected to your machine or the Simulator, follow these steps to see crashes:

1. Launch the Simulator.
2. Hit "Stop" in Xcode.
3. Launch your app in the Simulator and cause a crash.
4. Hit Run in Xcode.
5. The crash report will show up and you can see console output indicating that the report has been sent.

Comment: Oh ok, I disconnected from the debugger and start to receive new crash info. Thank you!

Comment: @Mike Bonnell, The crash got disappeared within 4 days, what could be the reason?

Comment: @Vignesh that isn't enough information to dive into this, I would send an email to support(at)fabric(dot)io with the crash that you're not seeing, the bundle id of your app, any missing dSYM info and filters applied to your dashboard.

Comment: @MikeBonnell, In your answer, you have mentioned, if you don't get the dSYM within 7 days, then the crash will not be processed and removed. In our case, the crash got disappeared within 4 days.

Comment: Again, I would recommend contacting the support team so that they can dig into the specifics of your situation. I mentioned the general behavior of how crashes are handled with a missing dSYM. If you don't have that scenario, then the support team can help.